# Responsive Wordpress Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i have the following website :http://mall-haine.ro/
I can't figure it out how to make it resize for the Mobile devices. 
Could you help me pls?
 i have tried to use CSS like

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {

}

and i don't understand what should i write there..

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: i've tried css but i can't figure it out ... could you give me some starting points ? like 
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
 main {
 
}
and what sould i write inside?

Comment: inspect css in browser console and start editing the live edit styles to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
 body { font-size:0.7em; }
```

}

Also, read [here](http://www.webdesignshock.com/responsive-web-design/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the bit:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px)
```

means what follows inside the braces will apply only on devices with screens less than or equal to 480px (i.e. mobiles, when they are no bigger than that). So inside the braces you put CSS that you only want to apply to such mobiles.

It's perfectly standard CSS (apart from being inside this extra pair of braces), but is intended to override what you have already specified for larger screens. And in order to override the large screen stuff, it must go *after* the large screen stuff. So:

```
div.sidebar {
    color : red;
    border : 1px solid blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    div.sidebar {
        color : green;
    }
}
```

The default CSS now says that, for all screens, the sidebar div will have a red font, and blue border.

But for mobiles up to 480px, you have said don't use a red font, use green instead. But you've said nothing about border in the media query, so that will remain blue on mobiles same as for desktops.

So the media query only holds CSS rules where you want a different style from what you specified for the default. The most common use of a media query is where you have boxes of content side by side on desktops, usually in floated divs. There's no room for that on the mobile, so you would specify `float:none;` inside a media query for smaller screens (which could use a min-width that takes in tablets as well as mobiles). The float:none forces the divs to show one below the other instead of side by side, so the content will be much larger and more readable on the small screen.

I hope this explains things well enough for you to get started. Experiment with that, then for futher info Google for media queries.